# How to choose production server/cloud for Apache Solr 5.1.0?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, solr

I have configured **Apache Solr 5.1.0** in my pc for searching server for my application.

Now I want to upload it on LIVE server for production environment. Many people suggested me to use Amazon Web Services(AWS) but I don't know about

```
EC2 or VPC
```

How to choose among these & Which plan is good for normal Solr application for Indian Region ??

Is there any other service for Solr Hosting??

Answer (score 1):

Realistically dude, no one is going to tell you here what is going to be the best for your setup. Especially considering your post has 0 technical information or requirements.

Do yourself a favor and develop requirements, compare various plans... all in all do your due-diligence.